# How can i Target CSS for Print based on browser and OS

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am trying to print an page which has header image and some text and when i print this page from Windows based on using FF, IE or Chrome it prints fine and when i check same using Print Preview in FF it show print scale at 60% but when i try to print same web page from MAC version of FF it prints the page and text on sides is cropped as page seems to be printing at 100 Scale.

Can i can target CSS separately for MAC based Firefox only so that i can assign width of container to 700pixels so that even if its scaled to 100% in Mac FF it still printer without cropping part of text.

is there a way by CSS i can target css for MAC OS version of Firefox only or i can only do this by code-behind using c#

I have already tried below CSS but this target FF on all OS

```
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
   .header{width:700px; }
   .content{ width:700px; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `media` rule for only `firefox` inside `media-print`

```css
    @media print {
      @-moz-document url-prefix() {/*only for firefox*/
        h1 {
          color: red;
        }
      }
      h1{color:blue;}/*other brwoser*/
    }
```

```html
<h1>I am title</h1>
<button onclick="window.print();">print</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I came across this but this will target FF on all Operating system. i am looking to target FF on MAC OS only which makes it difficult

Comment: try to add `@supports (-moz-osx-font-smoothing: auto) {
            #firefox-on-mac { color: green; }
          }` to `media-rule`

Comment: I dont think there is property for width `-moz-osx-width:700px`

Comment: try to add `and` to rule: `and (max-width: 700px){...}`